# Cross repeat red line css outer div

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to set repeat red line to its outer div at end of the page?

Here is the image [click here](https://s18.postimg.org/ehzuzdcdl/Lines_every_div_corner.png)

```
.crossline {
width: 2px;
height: 10px;
border-bottom: 1px solid red;
-webkit-transform:
translateY(-20px)
translateX(5px)
rotate(27deg);
position: relative;
```

}

Comment: You should probably use an image or possibly a `linear-gradient` for that.

Comment: @conexo thank you ! I have tried with it , could you send me a sample to set image on outer div?

Comment: `.outer-div { background-image: url(path/to/your/img.png) repeat; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something you could do, using repeating linear gradients.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 600px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #ff0000, #ff0000 1px, #ffffff 1px, #ffffff 10px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```